# How to control errors in mule 4?

Tags: error-handling, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4

There is a scheduler API that I have created, inside that there is a **for each** which is taking an array as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
Based on the value from the array I am using a **choice router**.
Now if any error occurs when `payload == 2`, how should I control the error handling such that after catching the error the control should go to `payload == 3`
No batching is used in this API.

Comment: Not enough information. Why pass an array to the for-each (why not just call 6 subflows one after the other?). Why does a scheduler receive a payload? What are the scheduling requirements?

Comment: The question has no apparent relationship with Mule 4 schedulers so the title is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a a Try scope with error handling inside the choice branch for payload == 2 to handle the error with on-continue to capture the error.

Note that there is nothing ache specific in your question or in  this solution.